# p:fileUpload inside p:dialog losing @ViewScoped values

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, view-scope

I'm trying to update multiple files with `<p:fileUpload>`. After I upload the files, I set a List with the paths that works fine.

After that the user then has to fill some other optional information and then click on a button(to submit the form).

When the user clicks on the button all the information about the list that was done on the `public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event)` is lost.

I need to save the paths on the database only when the user clicks on the button, i don't understand why the values are being lost, I'm using `@javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`

Also when the `handleFileUpload` is being processed the inputs made on the screen by the user are not yet available.

- JSF 2.2
- CDI
- PrimeFaces 5.1

I will omit some parts on the code below to avoid making it huge (if you think there's not enough info just tell me)

XHTML :

```
<h:form>
    <!-- OMITED -->
    <p:dialog>
        <!-- OMITED -->
        <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{csrBean.handleFileUpload}"
            mode="advanced"
            skinSimple="true"
            cancelLabel="Cancelar"
            multiple="true"
            auto="false"/>
        <!-- OMITED -->
    </p:dialog>
    <!-- OMITED -->
</h:form>
```

The method:

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    UploadedFile file = event.getFile();
    String normalize = FilenameUtils.normalize("uploads/csr/"
            + csr.getNumero() + "/" + event.getFile().getFileName());
    File destino = new File(normalize);
    try {
        FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(file.getInputstream(), destino);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    CsrOsAnexo anexo = new CsrOsAnexo();
    anexo.setCaminho(normalize);
    anexo.setOs(csr.getRespostaRecente().getOs());      
    csr.getRespostaRecente().getOs().getAnexoList().add(anexo);


    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile()
            .getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
}
```

Debugging, I can see the `csr.getRespostaRecente().getOs().getAnexoList()` filled with all the archives paths but as soon as the `handleFileUpload()` ends and I go to the method called by the commandButton, those values are gone and the values of the form are filled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A modal dialog **must** have its own form.

```
<h:body>
    ...
    <p:dialog>
        <h:form>
            ...
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
</h:body>
```

Because, when the modal dialog is generated into HTML output, it's by JavaScript relocated to the end of HTML `<body>` which causes it to not be sitting in any form anymore. This relocation is necessary to guarantee compatibility with older browsers (read: IE<9) having trouble with modal overlays and z-indexes. The generated HTML DOM tree ends up to look like this (use webbrowser's dev tools to see it):

```
<body>
    ...
    <form>
        ...
    </form>
    ...
    <div class="ui-dialog ...">
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

That the file upload apparently still worked without the form is because it autocreates a hidden iframe with therein a form to simulate the "ajax experience". However, any other action would basically lose the JSF view state and any view scoped bean would therefore get recreated.

Comment: Perfect, worked as a charm thank you