# ViewScoped bean is recreated each ajax request using p:remoteCommand

Tags: jsf, primefaces, view-scope, remotecommand

I have a javascript function responsible to call 2 managed bean methods using `<p:remoteCommand/>` the problem is that in one method i have to generate a value and use it in the second method, but when I call to the second method the value is null and this is because the ManagedBean is recreated each request, here is my code:

**javascriptFile.js**

```
<script>
function executeProcess(){
      method1();
      method2();
}
</script>
```

**myView.xhtml**

```
<h:form>
<p:remoteCommand name="method1"
                        actionListener="#{controller.method1()}"
                        update="xComponent" />
<p:remoteCommand name="method2"
                        actionListener="#{controller.method2()}"
                        update="xComponent" />

</h:form>
```

**Controller.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SearchCarneStudent implements Serializable {
     private String myValue;

     public void method1(){
           myValue="Hello";
     }

     public void method2(){
         System.out.println(myValue);  //<- This line is returning null because the bean is recreated each request
     }    

}
```

I hope you can help me

Thanks

Comment: Do you have correct import for `@ViewScoped`? `javax.faces.bean`

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/q/5541813

Comment: So you are saying a `p:commandButton` does not have this problem? Or a plain jsf `h:commandButton` in combination with an `f:ajax`?

Comment: Hello, Yes i have the correct import – Geinmachi     I tried adding   <context-param>
     <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
     <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param> to my web.xml but I still have the same problem.  – BalusC     And I'm not using commandButton I'm only using remote commands.

Comment: TRY with both... does it fail too? Then the issue is not remotecommand related