# @ViewScoped is recreated after button action on WebLogic

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, weblogic

First of all I know some other similar questions about my title, but My issue is a little bit different... When I try to initialize `LazyDataModel` in my `@ViewScoped` Bean it works fine until I click the actionButton on my page. When My Bean is created, its `@PostConstruct` method works as expected and `LazyDataModel` filled up in that method then datatable populated well. But when ajax called by actionButton in my page then entire bean recreated and `@PostConstruct` method called again, with that `LazyDataModel` value changing to `null`. Because of that, my page is crashing. In another scenario I was using `rowSelect` event in my datatable instead of actionButton with method which has a `SelectEvent` parameter. In SelectEvent parameter object field of it was null and I was getting `NullPointerException`. These are the scenarios... As result I guess when I use LazyDataModel in my `@ViewScoped` bean It calls PostConstruct again and my datamodel returns null for my SelectEvent method.

This is my `ViewScoped PostConstruct` method

```
@ManagedBean (name = "myEctrInboxBB")
@ViewScoped
public class MyEContractInboxBackingBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 2399679621562918360L;

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyEContractInboxBackingBean.class);

@ManagedProperty("#{ectrDomainService}")
EContractDomainService ectrDomainService;

@ManagedProperty("#{eContractUtil}")
EContractUtilBean eContractUtil;

@ManagedProperty("#{ectrApproveController}")
EContractApproveControllerBean ectrApproveController;

private EContractInboxItem selectedInboxRow;
private LazyEContractInboxItemModel lazyEcontractInboxItem;

private List<EContractInboxItem> inboxItems = new ArrayList<EContractInboxItem>();
private List<EContractInboxItem> filteredInboxItems = new ArrayList<EContractInboxItem>();

@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    User portalUser = getUser();
    List<String> userRoles = fetchUserRoles(portalUser);
    List<String> userSmCodes = fetchUserSmCodes(userRoles, portalUser);

    lazyEcontractInboxItem = new LazyEContractInboxItemModel(ectrDomainService, eContractUtil, userRoles, userSmCodes);


}

public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
    logger.info("**************************" + selectEvent);
}

public void openSelectedJob(EContractInboxItem item) {
ectrApproveController.openEContractInfoPage(item.getProcessInstanceId());
}
```

LazyDataModel

```
public class LazyEContractInboxItemModel extends LazyDataModel<EContractInboxItem>{

List<EContractInboxItem> inboxItems = new ArrayList<EContractInboxItem>();
List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<Task>();

EContractDomainService ectrDomainService;
EContractUtilBean ectrUtilBean;

List<String> userRoles = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> userSmCodes = new ArrayList<String>();

public LazyEContractInboxItemModel(EContractDomainService ectrDomainService, EContractUtilBean utilBean, List<String> roles,
        List<String> smCodes) {

    userRoles.addAll(roles);
    userSmCodes.addAll(smCodes);
    ectrUtilBean = utilBean;

    this.ectrDomainService = ectrDomainService;
}


public List<EContractInboxItem> getInboxItems() {
    return inboxItems;
}

public void setInboxItems(List<EContractInboxItem> inboxItems) {
    this.inboxItems = inboxItems;
}



@Override
public List<EContractInboxItem> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder,
        Map<String, Object> filters) {
    taskList = ectrDomainService.findTaskListAssignedToUserByUser(userRoles, userSmCodes);

    inboxItems.clear();

    inboxItems.addAll(ectrUtilBean.retrieveInboxItems(taskList));

    setRowCount(inboxItems.size());

    return inboxItems;
}


@Override
public List<EContractInboxItem> load(int first, int pageSize, List<SortMeta> multiSortMeta,
    Map<String, Object> filters) {
    taskList = ectrDomainService.findTaskListAssignedToUserByUser(userRoles, userSmCodes);

    inboxItems.clear();

    inboxItems.addAll(ectrUtilBean.retrieveInboxItems(taskList));

    setRowCount(inboxItems.size());

    return inboxItems;
}


@Override
public Object getRowKey(EContractInboxItem object) {
    return object.getProcessInstanceId();
}


@Override
public EContractInboxItem getRowData() {
    return super.getRowData();
}


@Override
public EContractInboxItem getRowData(String rowKey) {

    for (EContractInboxItem eContractInboxItem : inboxItems) {
        if (rowKey.equals(eContractInboxItem.getProcessInstanceId()))
            return eContractInboxItem;

    }
    return null;

}
getters and setters
```

xhtml page with actionButton

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ui:composition
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

<h:form
    id="eContractWaitingApprovalForm"
    prependId="false"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p:messages id="topmsgForEcontractWaitingApproval" />

    <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive">
            <p:dataTable
                id="waitingEcontracts"
                widgetVar="waitingEcontracts"
                styleClass="grid-sm-bottom"
                rows="20"
                resizableColumns="true"
                resizeMode="expand"
                paginator="true"
                lazy="true"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,50,100,200"
                value="#{myEctrInboxBB.lazyEcontractInboxItem}"
                var="item">

                <p:column
                    styleClass="center-column"
                    headerText="#{i18n['e-contract.dt.waiting.agreement.no']}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.eContract.eContractCode}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column
                    styleClass="center-column"
                    headerText="#{i18n['e-contract.dt.waiting.agreement.subject']}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.eContract.eContractSubject}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column
                    styleClass="center-column"
                    headerText="#{i18n['e-contract.dt.waiting.agreement.date']}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.eContract.eContractDate}">
                        <f:convertDateTime
                            type="date"
                            pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>

                <p:column
                    styleClass="center-column"
                    headerText="#{i18n['e-contract.dt.waiting.agency.name']}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.agencyName}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column
                    styleClass="center-column"
                    headerText="#{i18n['e-contract.dt.waiting.agency.type']}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.agencyType}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column
                    styleClass="center-column"
                    headerText="#{i18n['e-contract.dt.waiting.agency.sales.manager']}">
                    <h:outputText
                        value="#{myEctrInboxBB.findSalesOfficeBySmCode(item.agencySM)}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column
                    styleClass="center-column"
                    headerText="#{i18n['e-contract.dt.waiting.agreement.status']}">
                    <h:outputText
                        value="#{item.eContract.eContractStatus eq 'INPROGRESS' ? i18n['e-contract.dt.waiting.inprogress'] : item.eContract.eContractStatus}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column styleClass="center-column">
                    <p:commandButton
                        process="@this"
                        icon="ui-icon-search"
                        value="#{i18n['e-contract.dt.waiting.see.detail']}"
                        action="#{myEctrInboxBB.openSelectedJob(item)}" />
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

    </div>
</h:form>
```

xhtml page with rowSelect

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ui:composition
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

<h:form
    id="eContractWaitingApprovalForm"
    prependId="false"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p:messages id="topmsgForEcontractWaitingApproval" />

    <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive">
            <p:dataTable
                id="waitingEcontracts"
                widgetVar="waitingEcontracts"
                styleClass="grid-sm-bottom"
                rows="20"
                resizableColumns="true"
                resizeMode="expand"
                paginator="true"
                lazy="true"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,50,100,200"
                value="#{myEctrInboxBB.lazyEcontractInboxItem}"
                var="item"
                selection="#{myEctrInboxBB.selectedInboxRow}"
                selectionMode="single"
                rowKey="#{item.processInstanceId}">

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{myEctrInboxBB.onRowSelect}"/>

                <p:column
                    styleClass="center-column"
                    headerText="#{i18n['e-contract.dt.waiting.agreement.no']}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.eContract.eContractCode}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column
                    styleClass="center-column"
                    headerText="#{i18n['e-contract.dt.waiting.agreement.subject']}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.eContract.eContractSubject}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column
                    styleClass="center-column"
                    headerText="#{i18n['e-contract.dt.waiting.agreement.date']}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.eContract.eContractDate}">
                        <f:convertDateTime
                            type="date"
                            pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>

                <p:column
                    styleClass="center-column"
                    headerText="#{i18n['e-contract.dt.waiting.agency.name']}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.agencyName}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column
                    styleClass="center-column"
                    headerText="#{i18n['e-contract.dt.waiting.agency.type']}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.agencyType}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column
                    styleClass="center-column"
                    headerText="#{i18n['e-contract.dt.waiting.agency.sales.manager']}">
                    <h:outputText
                        value="#{myEctrInboxBB.findSalesOfficeBySmCode(item.agencySM)}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column
                    styleClass="center-column"
                    headerText="#{i18n['e-contract.dt.waiting.agreement.status']}">
                    <h:outputText
                        value="#{item.eContract.eContractStatus eq 'INPROGRESS' ? i18n['e-contract.dt.waiting.inprogress'] : item.eContract.eContractStatus}" />
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

    </div>
</h:form>
```

When I clicked a row of Datatable selectEvent.getObject() --> NULL always with LazyDataModel.

**A big important information: These all situations happens in *WebLogic 10.3.6.0* and works on TomCat like charm (even with LazyDataModel).**

***My Development environment:*** JSF 2.0, Primefaces 5.2, Liferay 6.2.3 ga4 with TomCat 7.04.
**Testing environment:** Same all except WebLogic 10.3.6.0 **(Problem only occurs on here)**

I really appreciate if someone could help me... Thanks in advance!!!

**EDIT:**

```
@ManagedBean (name = "myEctrInboxBB")
@ViewScoped
public class MyEContractInboxBackingBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 2399679621562918360L;

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyEContractInboxBackingBean.class);

@ManagedProperty("#{ectrDomainService}")
private transient EContractDomainService ectrDomainService;

@ManagedProperty("#{eContractUtil}")
private EContractUtilBean eContractUtil;

@ManagedProperty("#{ectrApproveController}")
private EContractApproveControllerBean ectrApproveController;

private EContractInboxItem selectedInboxRow;
private LazyEContractInboxItemModel lazyEcontractInboxItem;


@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    User portalUser = getUser();
    List<String> userRoles = fetchUserRoles(portalUser);
    List<String> userSmCodes = fetchUserSmCodes(userRoles, portalUser);

    lazyEcontractInboxItem = new LazyEContractInboxItemModel(userRoles, userSmCodes);
}
```

We can access Spring Beans like that:

```
    public EContractProcessService geteContractProcessService() {
    ELContext elContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
    return (EContractProcessService) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication()
        .getELResolver().getValue(elContext, null, "eContractProcessService");
}
```

Comment: So nothing of this has helped? http://stackoverflow.com/q/5541813

Comment: We worked a lot on this and realize something on ManagedBeans that if it has non-serializable fields, it can not be stored in FacesContext. When we change these fields as `transient`, they can be stored in FacesContext and in ajax calls we can access it from FacesContext (only in WebLogic). Btw, We use Spring beans not CDI. We look at your article and didnt match with our case. As a result when bean fields has became as `transient` there is no problem left. But We confused about using all Spring beans and fields as `transient`. Is that correct way to do it? @BalusC . Thank you.

Comment: We edited our post you can take a look at it. Btw our Mojarra version 2.1.21. Thanks. @BalusC