# Why does the backing bean get created twice first time dialog is launched?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces UI library for my web UI project.

I have a `manage_watchfolder.xhtml` page that has a button, and this button launches a dialog:

```
<p:commandButton value="Add" oncomplete="dlgEditWF.show()" update=":editWFForm">  
    <f:param value="#{item.value.ID}" name="editId"/>
    <h:graphicImage value="./edit.png" />
</p:commandLink>
```

Inside this same file I have `dlgEditWF` included from `edit_watchfolder.xhtml`:

```
<p:dialog id="editDialog" widgetVar="dlgEditWF" dynamic="true">
    <ui:include src="edit/edit_watchfolder.xhtml"/>
</p:dialog>
```

I am using `dynamic=="true"` to prevent `edit_watchfolder.xhtml` from being loaded before the button is clicked.

`editWFForm` is a form in `edit_watchfolder.xhtml`.

Problem is that when I launch the dialog for the *first* time, the `edit_watchfolder.xhtml` backing bean (request scoped) gets created twice. First time the value passed with `editId` (see above code) is OK, but second time it is not there, so the backing bean gets wrong values.

After I go back (`OK` or `Cancel` buttons) to the parent page and launch the dialog again, the problem is gone, all is OK. The problem seems to be only the first launch.

Why does the backing bean get created twice first time dialog is launched?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826377/jsf-backing-bean-constructor-called-multiple-times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this is because of how the Primefaces `dynamic` functionality works.

The first request by the commandButton will send the request parameter with the editID to load.  After this request occurs and the response is received and the page elements are updated, the `oncomplete` javascript occurs which displays the dialog.

Once the dialog is displayed *an entirely different request* occurs to *dynamically* load the contents of the dialog, except this time there is no editID parameter.  Your bean is `@RequestScoped` therefore it is being created twice and the second time it does not retain the editID request parameter.

There are three possible solutions:

1. Remove the `dynamic` attribute from your dialog
2. Change your bean to `@ViewScoped` or `@SessionScoped`.
3. Change the editID request parameter to a bean property in a `@SessionScoped` managed bean.

Comment: Thanks. The problem goes away if instead of `oncomplete` I use `onstart`. In that case dialog appears immediately - but empty - then after a secodn or two it gets updated with ajax to proper values. So, `onclick` works, but user experience is really bad.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is because first time you open dialog AJAX request is sent to load actual content. The only reasonable here is to use `@ViewScoped` bean which will handle both requests: first which is fired by `commandButton` and seconds which is fired by `dlgEditWF.show()`. Of course if you remove `dynamic="true"` there will be just one request.