# selectBooleanCheckbox value doesn't set properly inside ui:repeat

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2

i have a ui repeat on a composite as follows:

**-the ui repeat:**

```
<ui:repeat var="award" value="#{myBean.awards}" varStatus="status">
    <mycomp:Award id="awardComp" value="#{award}" index="#{status.index}"></mycomp:Award>
</ui:repeat>
```

**-the composite**

```
<h:panelGroup id="cashRow" layout="block" style="height:30px">
<label id="anniversaryAwardCash" class="admin checkbox" style="float: left; clear: both; margin-top: 10px; width: 100px;"> 
  <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{cc.attrs.value.cash}" style="margin-right:2px;" id="isanniversaryAwardCash"  >
     <f:ajax event="click"  render="cashRow" />
  </h:selectBooleanCheckbox> 
  <i></i>#{msg['action.givecash']}
</label>
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="anniversaryAwardCashInputDiv" rendered="#{cc.attrs.value.cash}"  styleClass="field-container  input-prepend" style="clear: both;">
    <span class="add-on">$</span>
    <h:inputText id="anniversaryAwardCashCashInput" required="true" requiredMessage="#{validation['rule.positive.number.for.amount']}" placeholder="#{msg['amount']}" title="#{msg['amount']}" value="#{cc.attrs.value.awardDollars}"
        maxlength="19" converterMessage="#{validation['rule.positive.number.for.amount']}"
        styleClass="#{component.valid?'':'field-error'}">
    </h:inputText>
</h:panelGroup>
```

when i check the checkbox, something unchecks it, i don't know what is doing that, please advise why how to fix this behavior.

Comment: It's hard to suspect the behavior with the above information but possible chances are check whether the particular id is getting again, form is getting refreshed and use firebug to debug to identify why it's getting triggered again.

Comment: @MohanaRao SV, i am rendering the whole div that contains the checkbox, when i render only the other input the checkbox is working fine but the other element won't show.

Comment: Might be known bug in mojarra https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3101

Comment: @Srikanth Ganji is it fixed ?

Comment: Did you check that the checkboxes have been assigned an unique id? If not then it's obvious why it's not working. The proposed solution to put it in datatable probably fixes it because the datatable will create unique ids itself for the checkboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently that it's a bug and it's fixed in JSF version 2.2.7

Comment: @CelinHC i hate jsf because of those lots of bugs